# Typescript 3 Angular 7 StopPropagation and PreventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, angular7, event-bubbling, typescript3.0

I have a text input inside a div. Clicking on the input should set it to focus and stop the bubbling of the div click event. I've tried the `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` on the text input event but to no avail. The console logs shows that the div click still executes regardless. How to stop the div click event from executing?

```
// html
<div (click)="divClick()" >
  <mat-card mat-ripple>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>
        <div style="width: 100px">
          <input #inputBox matInput (mousedown)="fireEvent($event)" max-width="12" />
        </div>
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
  </mat-card>
</div>


// component
@ViewChild('inputBox') inputBox: ElementRef;
divClick() {
    console.log('click inside div');
}

fireEvent(e) {
    this.inputBox.nativeElement.focus();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('click inside input');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have two different events, one is `mousedown` and another is `click`.

The e.stopPropagation() only works if both of the events are of the same kind.

You can change the input like this to work as expected:

```
<input #inputBox matInput (click)="fireEvent($event)" max-width="12" />
```

**Live example:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-basic-stack-55598740?file=app/input-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 20):

You can only stop propagation for the same event.

Your `fireEvent` function stops propagation for your `mousedown` event, but not for your `click` event.

If you want to stop propagation to click, try to add another click event on the input and stop propagation from there

For instance

```
<input #inputBox matInput (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" max-width="12" />
```

Your other function only needs to know what is required, that is, set focus

```
fireEvent(e) {
    this.inputBox.nativeElement.focus();
    console.log('click inside input');
}
```

`preventDefault()` prevents the default behaviour, it is not related to bubbling or not the events, so you can safely ignore it

Answer (score 5):

Try with `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"`. It might help as it worked for me in my scenario.