# stoppropagation not working as expected in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom-events

Here is the sample html layout of my component:

```
<div class="row align-content-start m-0">
  <div *ngFor="let child of list$ | async" class="col-12 mb-3" (click)="clickFunction(child)">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="flex-grow-1 border-left px-2 h-100 py-2">
       NAME
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex" (click)="selectDefault($event,child)" *ngIf="isEdit && child.isChecked">
    <i id="company_default" class="material-icons" [ngClass]="child.isDefault ? 'icon-success':''">flag</i>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngIf="isEdit">
    <input name="{{child.name}}" id="id_{{child.name}}" type="checkbox"
      class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="child.isChecked" (change)="checkBoxSelection($event)" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_{{child.name}}">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now as you can see there are three functions which are called based on events. `selectDefault()` it's working fine but if I choose a checkbox the `checkBoxSelection()` and `clickFunction()` are both called. On selecting a checkbox I don't want to trigger the `clickFunction()`. Here is the check box function:

```
checkBoxSelection(event: Event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
 }
```

Please help me to find out the issue / solution.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem because of two different events - `click` and `change`.

Take a look here [Typescript 3 Angular 7 StopPropagation and PreventDefault not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551821/typescript-3-angular-7-stoppropagation-and-preventdefault-not-working)

Hope that this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your guidance. This resolve my issue.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngIf="isEdit" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  <<<<checkbox here >>>>>>>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

two events are happening in the background that have no correlation to one another.
1. the change of the checkbox model
2. the click on the checkbox

you can try to do something like this

```
<input name="{{child.name}}" id="id_{{child.name}}" type="checkbox"
      class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="child.isChecked" (change)="checkBoxSelection($event)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"  />
```

Hope this helps!